# How Do I Create an object that holds more objects In Java?

Tags: java, object

Hi I'm doing a project in Java and I need to create a Diet object which will have 7 different days as attributes or perhaps make a separate class "DayOfTheWeek" so for example: Monday - Sunday, than each day must hold 6 objects of type Meal e.g: meal1,meal2 and finally the Meal object must hold three objects of type Food so for example FoodItem1,FoodItem2 and its attributes.

The information for food will be retrieved from database, and the Diet object must be also stored into a database. 
My problem is that I don't know how to model this. My initial idea was  to create Array of "Food" objects while creating a "Meal" object, and than while creating the "Day" object create an array of meals and so on until I create the Diet. 
However I would like some suggestions if there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: You can read a tutorial on Inheritance, Composition and OOP in general; So, it seems pretty straight-forward here if you isolate similarities into a super class then start from there.

Comment: Just do it!  You'll not get it perfectly right, but you will learn a lot more than if you follow some formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an array in your Diet object that stores Day objects. Each day object has aggregates of Meal objects which has aggregates of Food. Essentially you would have an array in Diet object of Days, that have Meals, that has Food. You could have Food inherit from Meals as well.